# how to make a single actionlistener function for many components

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

i have the following code in my actionlistener .it's working fine.

```
private void setActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    Container ct=button1.getParent();
    String panel_name=ct.getName();
    String button_val=button1.getText();
    textfield1.setText(panel_name+"-"+button_val);
}
```

but i have around 50 numbers of button.so i want to make a call to the function(setActionPerformed) in all the actionlistener of all the buttons.
so i tried the following

```
private void setActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    Container ct=this.getParent();
    String panel_name=ct.getName();
    String button_val=this.getText();
    textfield1.setText(panel_name+"-"+button_val);
}
```

but its not working!! any sgsn??

Comment: **How** is it not working? What happens?

Comment: Format your code if you want people to take the time and read your code.

Comment: can't we use (this) like that??

Comment: No, you'll likely need to pass in the Button as an argument

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're looking for [ActionEvent#getSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)

```
JButton button = (JButton) evt.getSource();
String buttonText = button.getText();
```

Comment: thnx a lot ....
problem solved.
but can u tell me why cant we use direct this.getName
what is the function of getSource?

Comment: Because `this` doesnt refer to the `JButton` but rather to whichever class implemented the `ActionListener`

Comment: As the name suggests `getSource` gets the source object which caused the `ActionEvent`...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem, you want to re-use the same code for each of your buttons. You should create a class that inherits from `ActionListener` and in the `setActionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method, you should use `e.getSource()` to know which button has been pressed.

You just have to use `addActionListener(ActionListener)` with an instance of this new class as parameter.